# C program using strcat keeps giving unexpected output at runtime

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that is able to rotate at point k, defined as the "rotation requested."

Example: rotate("derp", 3) => pder

My code for this function is called rotate, as listed below. It takes in both a char pointer array, startString, as defined in my main, and the number of rotations (A long int because I use atol to get the integer from the command line).

```
int rotate(char *startString, long int rotations) {
    char *doubleString = malloc((sizeof startString * 2) + sizeof(char));
    strcat(doubleString, startString);
    strcat(doubleString, startString);
    long int stringSize = (sizeof startString - 1);
    long int breakIndex = (rotations % stringSize);
    char* rotatedString = malloc((sizeof startString + sizeof(char)));

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < stringSize + 1; i++) {
        char pushedCharacter = doubleString[(int)breakIndex + i];
        strcat(rotatedString, &pushedCharacter);
    }

    printf("%s\n", rotatedString);
    printf("%s\n", doubleString);
    return 0;

}
```

But, when I output, if I use something like doghouse I get a weird ?4??? in front of the output for the rotatedString. It also completely doesn't work for derp, instead printing out pderp with the same ?4??? in front. Where is this runtime error being caused?

**EDIT**

The answer given was correct, but the goal was to be able to accept rotations greater than the length of the given string. That code is below:

```
void rotate(char * startString, long int rotations) {
    long int stringSize = strlen(startString);

    long int breakIndex = (rotations % stringSize);
    char *rotatedString = malloc(stringSize + 1); //counting extra char for null terminator
    strncpy(rotatedString, startString + breakIndex, stringSize - breakIndex);
    strncpy(rotatedString + stringSize - breakIndex, startString, breakIndex);
    rotatedString[stringSize] = '\0'; // for the ending null character of the char array

    printf("Result: %s\n", rotatedString);
    free(rotatedString);
```

}

Comment: 1) `char *doubleString = malloc((sizeof startString * 2) + sizeof(char));` malloc() does not initialize the memory. 2) sizeof startstring yields `sizeof (char*) ` 3) `sizeof (char)` is 1, by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doublestring initialization allocates too little memory because you're using sizeof(startstring), which is the size of a pointer, not strlen(startstring) + 1 which is the length of the string including the terminating NUL character. This means your code is overwriting the end of the buffer with hilarous results. Try the following:

```
void rotate(char * startString, int rotation) {
    int len = strlen(startString);
    if (len == 0 || len <= rotation)
        return;

    char *rotatedString = malloc(len + 1); /* One extra char for the terminating NUL */
    strncpy(rotatedString, startString + rotation, len - rotation);
    strncpy(rotatedString + len - rotation, startString, rotation);
    rotatedString[len] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", rotatedString);
    free(rotatedString);       /* don't leak memory! */
}
```

Comment: This code worked fine, but we could not limit rotations. I'll make a quick edit for anyone else who finds this interesting.